# Where can awards be seen?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTAO, sometimes after you do a race or a jump, long wheelie, a little notification will pop up telling you you got an award for something. Where do you view these awards? All I can find are achievements (on steam) and there is nothing in the stats tab either.

Answer (score 2):

"Awards" can be found by logging into your social club account on [Rockstar Social Club](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com).

After logging in, navigate to the "Games" link, and select GTA V. From there, select "Career" from the menu and then "Stats" or "Awards" from the submenu. Here you will be able to view your various stats (wheelie distance, jump height, etc) and awards from the game.